# Send an email with data from a method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, nopcommerce

I would like to send an email with data collected from this method "DailyBestSellersReport" in Nopcommerce MVC/ASP:

```
public IList<BestsellersReportLine> DailyBestSellersReport(
            int recordsToReturn = 5, int orderBy = 1, int groupBy = 1)
        {
            var yesterday = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));
            var earliest = new DateTime(yesterday.Year, yesterday.Month, yesterday.Day, 0, 0, 0);
            var latest = earliest.Add(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0, -1));
            var CurrentDay = DateTime.Now;
            var DayBefore = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);


                var query1 = from opv in _opvRepository.Table
                         where earliest <= CurrentDay && latest >= DayBefore
                         join o in _orderRepository.Table on opv.OrderId equals o.Id
                         join pv in _productVariantRepository.Table on opv.ProductVariantId equals pv.Id
                         join p in _productRepository.Table on pv.ProductId equals p.Id
                         select opv;


                var query2 = groupBy == 1 ?
                    //group by product variants
                       from opv in query1
                       group opv by opv.ProductVariantId into g
                       select new
                       {
                           EntityId = g.Key,
                           TotalAmount = g.Sum(x => x.PriceExclTax),
                           TotalQuantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
                       }
                       :
                    //group by products
                       from opv in query1
                       group opv by opv.ProductVariant.ProductId into g
                       select new
                       {
                           EntityId = g.Key,
                           TotalAmount = g.Sum(x => x.PriceExclTax),
                           TotalQuantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity),
                       }
                       ;

                switch (orderBy)
                {
                    case 1:
                        {
                            query2 = query2.OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalQuantity);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        {
                            query2 = query2.OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalAmount);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentException("Wrong orderBy parameter", "orderBy");
                }

                if (recordsToReturn != 0 && recordsToReturn != int.MaxValue)
                    query2 = query2.Take(recordsToReturn);

                var result = query2.ToList().Select(x =>
                {
                    var reportLine = new BestsellersReportLine()
                    {
                        EntityId = x.EntityId,
                        TotalAmount = x.TotalAmount,
                        TotalQuantity = x.TotalQuantity
                    };
                    return reportLine;
                }).ToList();

                return result;

        }
```

Iv'e found that the following method sends an email:

```
[NopHttpsRequirement(SslRequirement.No)]
public ActionResult ContactUs()
{
    var model = new ContactUsModel()
    {
        Email = _workContext.CurrentCustomer.Email,
        FullName = _workContext.CurrentCustomer.GetFullName(),
        DisplayCaptcha = _captchaSettings.Enabled && _captchaSettings.ShowOnContactUsPage
    };
    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost, ActionName("ContactUs")]
[CaptchaValidator]
public ActionResult ContactUsSend(ContactUsModel model, bool captchaValid)
{
    //validate CAPTCHA
    if (_captchaSettings.Enabled && _captchaSettings.ShowOnContactUsPage && !captchaValid)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", _localizationService.GetResource("Common.WrongCaptcha"));
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string email = model.Email.Trim();
        string fullName = model.FullName;
        string subject = string.Format(_localizationService.GetResource("ContactUs.EmailSubject"), _storeInformationSettings.StoreName);

        var emailAccount = _emailAccountService.GetEmailAccountById(_emailAccountSettings.DefaultEmailAccountId);
        if (emailAccount == null)
            emailAccount = _emailAccountService.GetAllEmailAccounts().FirstOrDefault();

        string from = null;
        string fromName = null;
        string body = Core.Html.HtmlHelper.FormatText(model.Enquiry, false, true, false, false, false, false);
        //required for some SMTP servers
        if (_commonSettings.UseSystemEmailForContactUsForm)
        {
            from = emailAccount.Email;
            fromName = emailAccount.DisplayName;
            body = string.Format("<strong>From</strong>: {0} - {1}<br /><br />{2}", 
                Server.HtmlEncode(fullName), 
                Server.HtmlEncode(email), body);
        }
        else
        {
            from = email;
            fromName = fullName;
        }
        _queuedEmailService.InsertQueuedEmail(new QueuedEmail()
        {
            From = from,
            FromName = fromName,
            To = emailAccount.Email,
            ToName = emailAccount.DisplayName,
            Priority = 5,
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body,
            CreatedOnUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
            EmailAccountId = emailAccount.Id
        });

        model.SuccessfullySent = true;
        model.Result = _localizationService.GetResource("ContactUs.YourEnquiryHasBeenSent");

        //activity log
        _customerActivityService.InsertActivity("PublicStore.ContactUs", _localizationService.GetResource("ActivityLog.PublicStore.ContactUs"));

        return View(model);
    }

    model.DisplayCaptcha = _captchaSettings.Enabled && _captchaSettings.ShowOnContactUsPage;
    return View(model);
}
```

However i can't figure out what parts i need and how i would pass the data from "DailyBestSellersReport" and send it as an email.

Annyone with experience with this?

Thx

//Chriss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into `MessageTokenProvider` in `Nop.Service->Message` you will find methods which are used to create Html tables as token for the Email Template. Same can be applied in your case i.e. You can use your `result` as a parameter for method, this method will generate `Html` table. And you can add this as a token in your email.

Get back if any doubts!

Comment: You mean like creating new tokens and a new message template? I thought it would be simpler just sending an email without this process just like the "ContactUs" method above that dosn't use a message template. Thx

Comment: Yes you can also do that, you just need to create html table then and send it as a body for email But its better to have Message template as it gives you flexibility and makes your code more maintenable

Comment: What steps would you take to acomplish this? For example: 1, add a new template in the DB MessageTemplates Table. 2: Add tokens. 3: Create message template in WorkFlowMessageService ..etc..?

Comment: Exactly. You need to create meassage template with required tokens. You can then view this template and edit at http://yoursite.com/Admin/MessageTemplate/List and add tokens to it. These tokens then can be replaced with actual data in MessageTokenProvider service which is called from WorkFlowMessaginService. Please check example for Email template for     order placed or other!